# Algorithms \And boolean operator casuing "Undefined Control Sequence" error

Tags: errors, algorithms, pseudocode

I'm writing some algorithms using the `algorithmicx` package.

I'm trying to create an `if` statement with an `And` boolean operator but using `\And` is causing an `Undefined Control Sequence` error

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\If{$i < j+bandSize$ \And $j < i+bandSize$}
    \State $DTW_{i,j}\gets min(DTW_{i,j-1},DTW_{i-1,j},DTW_{i-1,j-1})+(f[i]-s[j])^2$
\EndIf
```

What's causing this?

Comment: I suggest use the answer by Werner if you use the algorithmic package: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519442/213

Answer (score 15):

I did not find any `\And` in `algpseudocode` or `algorithmicx`, but you can easily add one:

```
\algnewcommand\And{\textbf{and}}
```

Comment: Since `\And` is typically used as a parameterless macro almost like a binary relation in text, using `\algnewcommand{\And}{\textbf{and}\xspace}` seems a good idea (of course, including the [`xspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace)).

Comment: Is it OK in pseudocode to use the logical and operator instead?

Comment: @Chris I think it depends on the pseudocode style you use. If you're not restricted, you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

just use `\&`. It works completely fine.

`\If{$i < j+bandSize$ \& $j < i+bandSize$}
    \State $DTW_{i,j}\gets min(DTW_{i,j-1},DTW_{i-1,j},DTW_{i-1,j-1})+(f[i]-s[j])^2$
\EndIf`

Example from the question is modified for a clear explanation.

Comment: Could you explain your answer in detail?

Comment: works really well!