# "and" in algorithm

Tags: algorithms

So I'm not experienced with the algorithm packages in LaTeX.  I'm assuming there must be a way to do

**if** condition1 **and** condition2 **then**...

but I can't find it.  I've checked what I can find of the documentation.  If I compile the below I get an error for undefined command at the \And.  It looks like there is something in algorithm, using `\AND`, but that doesn't work here and I don't really understand what's going on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[nothing]{algorithm}
\algrenewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\algrenewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{algorithmic}
\If{$x> y$ \And $ x<z$}
\State{some code here}
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to do what I'm after?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could not find a `\And` command but we can make one:

```
\algnewcommand\And{\textbf{and}}
```

and add some space...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[nothing]{algorithm}
\algrenewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\algrenewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\algnewcommand\And{\textbf{and} }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{algorithmic}
\If{$x> y$ \And  $ x<z$}
\State{some code here}
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

Thanks: @Werner

Comment: And what is the difference? Did you see the second par of the question?

Comment: Sorry I was confused with other algorithms package.

Comment: Note the use here should be `\And{}`, or define it to include a trailing space: `\algnewcommand\And{\textbf{and} }`.

Comment: @Werner, Thank you! (sorry I was editing and I just saw your suggestion). I don't know: perhaps your solution is better...

Comment: @JJoao: You would most likely not use `\And` unless you have two operands (one on either side), so it seems logical to define `\And` to *always* include a space. [`xspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace) is a viable option, noting of course that there might be some [drawbacks of using `xspace`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/5764).

Comment: For algorithmic `and` could I use: `$ $ \mathrm{and} $ $`?

Comment: \algnewcommand\And2{\textbf{and}}, since `\And` is defined previously and requires $ $.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest use the answer by Werner if you use the algorithmic package. Link: [Using the "algorithm" package - can't use \OR?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331514/using-the-algorithm-package-cant-use-or)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\algnewcommand{\algorithmicand}{\textbf{ and }}
\algnewcommand{\algorithmicor}{\textbf{ or }}
\algnewcommand{\OR}{\algorithmicor}
\algnewcommand{\AND}{\algorithmicand}
\algnewcommand{\var}{\texttt}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
  \Procedure{proc}{$v$}
    \State $\var{v.bool} \gets \var{v.bool} \OR \var{c.bool}$;
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```