# Using the "algorithm" package - can't use \OR?

Tags: algorithms

I keep getting an error...

```
! Undefined control sequence. \State $v.bool \gets v.bool \OR
```

Even though `\AND` works.  Is there something I'm missing.  A little late for me to switch to a different package but seems like something that should be supported.

Sample...

```
\begin{algorithmic}
    \Procedure{proc}{$v$}
        \State $v.bool \gets v.bool \OR c.bool$;
    \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
```

Comment: I will use \parallel for now

Comment: Please provide a small complete code sample we can use to reproduce that error.

Comment: K I've added it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be mixing the notation of [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) and [`algorithms`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) - both provide an `algorithmic` environment. *Define* something if it doesn't exist:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\algnewcommand{\algorithmicand}{\textbf{ and }}
\algnewcommand{\algorithmicor}{\textbf{ or }}
\algnewcommand{\OR}{\algorithmicor}
\algnewcommand{\AND}{\algorithmicand}
\algnewcommand{\var}{\texttt}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
  \Procedure{proc}{$v$}
    \State $\var{v.bool} \gets \var{v.bool} \OR \var{c.bool}$;
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```